# How to get complete page back in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, browser-cache

I was working on a js fiddle and got carried away. I did not think to save and then I hit the reload instead of run, and now I lost a bunch of work. Is there any way to get the cache back? All I need is three css / html / javascript text boxes content.